# AngularJS: How to write a two-level sorting function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

My goal is to write an AngularJS ordering function, which behaves similarily, for example, to MySQL's "ORDER BY column1, column2". Means: if "column1" is same, sort by "column2".

The solution for only one criterium is, as known:

```
$scope.myOrderFn = function (item) {
  return item.column1;
}
```

How to add the second criterium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be that the sort function is more a "order by key extract function".
Therefore you cannot just concat string values because this would break the sorting.
However, you can pass more than one sort function as you would with column names. It's not in the offical documentation but the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/orderBy.js?source=c) is straightforward.

I think your only option is to pass two sort functions as you would with the sort columns:

#### Template

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:['column1','column2']">
  {{item.column1}}-{{item.column2}}
</div>

<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:[sort1,sort2]">
  {{item.column1}}-{{item.column2}}
</div>
```

#### Controller

```
$scope.sort1 = function (item) {
  return item.column1;
}

$scope.sort2 = function (item) {
  return item.column2;
}
```

Comment: Actually it is [documented](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy), so: `|orderBy:['-desc', '+label', '-id']"` would work to sort by multiple columns. http://jsbin.com/uSaseRu/1/

Comment: @Yoshi: That's true. I was not clear about that. I meant multiple sort functions.

Comment: Stefan - it looks good and does what it should. Thank you. +1